# Azure SQL Server connect to External Data Source using Managed Identity database scoped credential

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

We have 2 databases in single Azure SQL Server. We have configured External Data Source to connect to one database from another database.

Currently, we have used **SQL server authentication** when we configured database scoped credentials. But due to compliance issue we are removing all SQL Server user and moving towards using (User) **Managed Identity** for all resources.

Is there a way to configured External Data Source using database scoped credentials which uses Managed Identity to connect to Azure SQL Server?

I tried few ways to assigned managed identity while altering Database Scoped Credential, but nothing worked.

`ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL`

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: I don't think this is supported. managed identity with scoped credentials only works with blob (last time i checked). not sure if it is an option but you could move your two databases to azure sql managed instance, that would give you more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

***Is there a way to configured External Data Source using database scoped credentials which uses Managed Identity to connect to Azure SQL Server?***

Agreed with @Thomas as per [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/resolve-elastic-query-issues-in-azure-sql-database/ba-p/3583451) Microsoft post.

> Azure Active Directory (AAD) principals are not supported in Elastic Query, only SQL Authentication will work.

**Managed Identity is in the scope of AAD principals and is also not supported. while creating credentials. The limitations restrict the use of AAD-based authentication methods within Elastic Query**

You can add feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/04fe6ee0-3b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0)